Why do we use generateStaticParams() when dynamic route params are already passed to page components?
In Next.js 14, dynamic route params are automatically passed to your page component. For example if you have a dynamic route products/[productid]/[variantid] your pages under those dynamic route segments have access to the values of productId and variantId.
As far as I can tell, generateStaticParams() does the same thing by returning an array of values that can be used in the route segments. So is there a reason to use generateStaticParams()?
From what I've seen, my app functions the same when I remove the generateStaticParams() call on my page for a route similar to the aforementioned one.

Any code in generateStaticParams is executed at build time and the data returned can be used to build the page. So long running data fetching can be avoided at run time.
